# How to prevent clearing of terminal output when I "exit" an SSH session?

Tags: bash, ssh

This is the situation: I open a terminal in Ubuntu, and do `ssh host-1`, which works as expected. From host-1, I do `ssh host-2`, which again works fine and connects me to host-2. From host-2 I do, for example, `echo "blah"`, which prints `blah` to the screen. Problem: If I do `exit`, the screen is cleared, and I am left with only the following:

`Connection to host-2 closed.`
`myusername$`

How can I prevent the clearing of output from the screen generated by commands run on host-2 (i.e. `blah`, etc.), after I `exit` back to host-1?

Some debugging I've already done: I've had a friend login to host-1 and host-2, exactly as above, and when he `exit`'s from host-2, his screen is NOT cleared. So it must be something to do with my environment...right? Any ideas what it could be?

I've tried this using PuTTY in Windows XP, and from a terminal in Ubuntu - same behaviour regardless.

Answer (score 33):

Check `~/.bash_logout`

It probably contains a `clear` command.
Comment that out.

Also, in a lot of terminals, (e.g. `gnometerm`) you can just scroll back up and see what was "cleared".

Comment: Yep, it was in ~/.bash_logout. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

You stated Ubuntu, but for the sake of others, if it is a recent updated cygwin, edit `/etc/bash.bash_logout` and comment out the following:

```
if [ "$SHLVL" = 1 ]; then
    [ -x /usr/bin/clear ] && /usr/bin/clear
fi
```

Future updates will not overwrite the file if it is modified.