# How can zsh be configured to not clear the screen at logout?

Tags: ssh, zsh

When sshing to a host, the screen is cleared at exit, which makes it impossible to review recent output. This behavior seems to be set system-wide in /etc/zlogout. How can zsh be configured to not clear the screen at logout?

Related question: [How to prevent clearing of terminal output when I "exit" an SSH session?](https://superuser.com/questions/186037/how-to-prevent-clearing-of-terminal-output-when-i-exit-an-ssh-session)

Answer (score 9):

The system-wide `/etc/zlogout` file can be overridden by adding the following to `.zlogout`:

```
setopt norcs
```

The `norcs` option signifies that zsh should not read any subsequent rc files, which includes `/etc/zlogout`. And since `/etc/zlogout` is the last processed rc file, the `norcs` option does not have any side effect when specified in `.zlogout`.